# Received SSDI income less than 15,000. Do I need to file income tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, social-security

I live alone, and received less than $15,000 from SSDI. Do I need to file income tax?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21405/is-it-necessary-to-file-taxes-if-youve-made-less-than-15-000-for-the-year

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, probably not:

http://www.irs.gov/Help-&-Resources/Tools-&-FAQs/FAQs-for-Individuals/Frequently-Asked-Tax-Questions-&-Answers/Social-Security-Income/Regular-&-Disability-Benefits/Regular-&-Disability-Benefits

But also keep in mind the IRS can challenge (i.e. Audit, assess, etc) that tax year indefinitely if you don't file.  By filing, the statute of limitation will begin and after three years the tax year is closed.

Comment: You should quote from the link to make sure that link rot doesn't cause this answer to be come worthless.